# Add entry to array inside an Observable object

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have an angular app where on one page I am displaying an object that includes an array of comments as a sub-object.
I load the object into my class as an Observable.
Then I display the object in my html by using the

```
<div class="container-fluid mt--7" *ngIf="drill | async as item else loading">
```

That way it has a display until the Observable loads.

As part of the page, you have the ability to append a new comment to the Drill object. Saving that object to the DB works fine, but I would like to just append the new comment to the Drill object so that I don't have to requery the Drill object from the DB to have the new comment displayed.

I just can't figure out how to update the Observable from inside the .subscribe method of service call to persist the new comment.

```
addComments(): void {
    const comment = new Comment(null, this.commentsForm.get('comment').value, this.commentsForm.get('rating').value);
    this.drillService.addComments(this.id, comment).subscribe(comment => {
     ---- This is where I can't figure out what to do ------
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update observable directly, There are 2 ways you can fix your issue.

1. Instead of using drill observable store comments in an array and push new comment into this array and use this array to display html side

2. Create a new observable using Subject (rxjs operater). You can find examples of how you can create observable using subject https://medium.com/globant/rxjs-subjects-the-complete-know-how-3dc1e7e341a0